# Fragment shader on plane with modified vertices

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader

I have a PlaneGeometry and I'm randomly animating the vertices in order to create random spikes.
I use this FragmentShader :

```
void main() {
       vec3 light = vec3(cos(time),sin(time),1.0);
       light = normalize(light);
       float dProd = max(0.0, dot(vNormal, light));
        gl_FragColor = vec4(dProd,dProd,dProd,1.0);
        }
```

I expected to have some faces of each spike colored in black, but instead I got a solid color. I placed a Sphere on my plane and applied the same shader:
[image]

When I turn the wireframe OFF :[image]

Not sure I understand what's happening on the plane?!  I thought that since each spike has different normals, they should have different lighting as well.

[Live Demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29486520/shader/EarthRender.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "spikes" do not have different vertex normals because you didn't change the vertex normals; they are all ( 0, 1, 0 ). This is something you could have checked yourself in the console.

Also, when you modify the vertices of a quad ( a face of the plane ), the four vertices are likely no longer planar. This will cause you all sorts of problems. ( google non-planar quads. )

You can avoid these problems by triangulating the `PlaneGeometry` first:

```
THREE.GeometryUtils.triangulateQuads( geometry );
```

Be advised that this function recomputes vertex normals. Have a look at the source so you understand what it is doing.

three.js r.58

Comment: Thx for your clear answer. I think, working with non planar quads as a start with THREE.js is not the best idea.