# threejs, Keep object on surface of another object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I m generating a terrain geometry like this:

```
     var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100, 100 , 100 );
     for (var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i++) {
          geometry.vertices[i].z  = Math.random() / 2;
     }
     geometry.computeFaceNormals();
     floor = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, floorMaterial);
```

and have another object3d that is supposed to walk on the floor surface.
how can i find out how much my object has to go up or down? maybe with raycaster.

[Edited]
well the the first part is solved, but the second part is that the distance that raycaster returns is not right, it s somehow flipped for each face. check the example:
http://myhtmltest.net76.net/raycast.html

Comment: Warning: You are generating non-planar quads. Your program will work perfectly if you follow the instructions in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243984/fragment-shader-on-plane-with-modified-vertices/17245047#17245047) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The THREE.Raycaster should work indeed, as you already guessed.

In the update loop you need to cast rays downwards

```
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
raycaster.set(yourMovingObject.position, THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0));
```

After that you will need to determine a distance from the ground where the object needs to stop 'falling'

```
var distance = 40; //set to your own measurements
```

And last but not least, check the intersections

```
var velocity = new THREE.Vector3();

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(floor); //use intersectObjects() to check the intersection on multiple

//new position is higher so you need to move you object upwards
if (distance > intersects[0].distance) {        
    yourMovingObject.position.y += (distance - intersects[0].distance) - 1; // the -1 is a fix for a shake effect I had
}

//gravity and prevent falling through floor
if (distance >= intersects[0].distance && velocity.y <= 0) {
    velocity.y = 0;
} else if (distance <= intersects[0].distance && velocity.y === 0) {
    velocity.y -= delta ;
}

yourMovingObject.translateY(velocity.y);
```

Something like this should work, but you will have to tweak it for your own environment.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it helped me to understand the concept but i m still not able to do it right.

Comment: ok i provided a link and the problem i m having is clear, just click a couple of times. http://myhtmltest.net76.net/raycast.html

Comment: the rays[i] was a typo. I will look into your example